# re.match() проверка по регулярному

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Нужна именно проверка строки на совпадение с *регулярным выражением*, а не поиск *подстрок*. Есть ли такая функция непосредственно в `re` пакете, или надо отдельно допиливать?

---

Пример кода:

```
string = sys.argv[1]
if re.match("dog{1}", string):
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

---

```
$ python3 rematch dog
yes
$ python3 rematch dogdog
yes
```

Во втором случае должна быть ошибка, ведь я ввел две *собаки*, а по логике программа должна пропустить только с одной *собакой*.

Если я чего не понимаю, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста пример строки и регулярное выражение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, нужно проверить, вся ли строка подходит под рег.выражение?

```
import re
a = "abc12def"
b = re.match(r"^\w{3}\d{2}\w{3}$", a)
print(b)
```

Если строка полностью подходит - функция вернёт объект `_sre.SRE_Match`, если нет - `None`

Результат:

> IN: abc12def
>
> OUT: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 8), match='abc12def'>
>
> IN: abc12defZ
>
> OUT: None

Comment: Да, спасибо, совсем забыл про `$`)